# How to correctly do a form with relationships and server side validations

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In an ember app, using JSON Api adapter, I have those models :

```
# subscription.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  userId: DS.attr(),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  courseId: DS.attr(),
  course: DS.belongsTo('course')
});

#contact.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  fullname: DS.attr(),
  phone: DS.attr(),
  email: DS.attr(),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
});

#user.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr(),
  subscriptions: DS.hasMany('subscription'),
  course: DS.hasMany('course'),
  contacts: DS.hasMany('contact')
});
```

Using [ember-rapid-form](https://github.com/piceaTech/ember-rapid-forms), I have this template :

```
{{#em-form model=model}}
  {{em-input model=model.user label="Email" property="email" canShowErrors=true}}
  {{em-select label="Course" property="course" content=courses canShowErrors=true prompt=" " propertyIsModel=true optionLabelPath="name"}}
  {{#each model.user.contacts as |contact|}}
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        {{em-input model=contact label="Name" property="fullname" canShowErrors=true}}
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        {{em-input model=contact label="Email" property="email" canShowErrors=true}}
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        {{em-input model=contact label="Phone" property="phone" canShowErrors=true}}
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
  <a {{action 'addContact' }}>Add contact</a>
{{/em-form}}
```

And this route :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    var subscription = this.store.createRecord('subscription');
    var user = this.store.createRecord('user');
    subscription.set('user', user);
    return subscription;
  },
  actions: {
    submit: function(token) {
      var subscription = this.controller.model;
      subscription.get('user').then((user) => {
        user.save().then(() => {
          subscription.save().then(() => {
            user.get('contacts').invoke('save');
            this.transitionTo('subscriptions.success');
          }, function() {} );
        })
      })
    },
    addContact: function() {
      var subscription = this.controller.model;
      subscription.get('user').then((user) => {
        var contact = this.store.createRecord('contact');
        user.get('contacts').pushObject(contact);
      })
    },
  }
});
```

It works but I have problems with my `submit` method. First, I think it's ugly, I don't like nested `then`. Secondly, if there is a failure with a server side validation, it will not continue and trigger other validations. If some models fail, others can be created on the server side.

I did not found any clean solution on the Internet. The best way can be to pass all data in a single xhr call. I tried without success to pass nested attributes on models.

What's the best way to do this kind of forms?

Comment: "The best way can be to pass all data in a single xhr call." - That's exactly what you need to do. You have have all of the data your need, just send it all together. In this case you can probably customize the create method on your adapters to send both models at once. Unfortunately there's no pattern or agreed upon way to do this, you just need to figure out a way that works for you and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [JSON API Roadmap for 1.1](http://jsonapi.org/about/#roadmap-1-1), you'll see "Embedding / creating multiple related resources in a single request". So for now, as [GJK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277669/gjk) said, you would need to override some methods on your adapters to roll your own implementation.